# Tobin's Annualized Standard Deviation in Pandas

Tags: pandas, standard-deviation

I am seeking to confirm that I have correctly calculated Tobin's formula for determining annualized standard deviation based on a series of monthly returns.

The most widespread (and easiest) way to calculate annualized standard deviation is to multiply the monthly standard deviation by the square root of 12.

[image: formula]

Morningstar, however, defers to James Tobin's formula for annualized standard deviation, [as linked here](https://corporate.morningstar.com/US/documents/MethodologyDocuments/MethodologyPapers/SquareRootofTwelve.pdf).

[image: formula]

Here's my representation of this formula in pandas, where observations is a data frame containing monthly returns.

```
observations.apply(lambda x: np.sqrt((((observations.std() ** 2) + ((1+observations.mean())**2))**12) - (1+observations.mean())**24) ).ix[:,0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy to vectorize your formula. I feel that beginners to pandas should never be allowed to use `apply` or `ix`. These should be your last options.

```
# variance is just square of std so you can use var
var = observations.var()
mean_one = observations.mean() + 1

np.sqrt(((var + (mean_one**2))**12) - mean_one**24)
```